# Storing Large Amount of Data in Session - Should I Do This?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

High level question here - I am developing a Spring MVC/Spring Data Project to search Tables in a database via Spring Repositories. The tables I am searching on will contain thousands, if not tens of thousands of records. I would like to hold onto these records in a `List` throughout the duration of using the application, until a condition is met where the `List` will be reset or removed.

My question is, is it feasible to store this `List` in my `HttpSession`?

- Should I expect any performance issues with this method?
- Is there a security concern if storing my `List` in the session?
- Are there any best practices anyone can offer for a task such as this?

A quick view of the user session info along side a small List of 4 objects (could potentially be thousands)

```
Session Attribute Name  Session Attribute Value
searchResults           [com.mysite.dto.User@322bfb87,
                         com.mysite.dto.User@658e75cc, 
                         com.mysite.dto.User@6bd7d82a, 
                         com.mysite.dto.User@27b0e4b6]
userRoles               [ROLE_ADMIN]
username                admin
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

i would store them in a cache but not in session. You can use external caches like BigMemory Terracotta (http://terracotta.org/products/bigmemory) or memcache (Amazon provides an easy to use one if you are running your application in the EC2). This will be much more scale able than your servers JVM heap.

another idea would be to store in cache a reference of the user id with the user object and now in session you can store only the ids. That way your session saves only numbers instead of whole objects